# No bootable medium found on VirtualBox

Tags: windows, virtual-machine, virtualbox, windows-server

I'm trying to run Windows Server 2012 on VirtualBox.

1. I created a new virtual machine with these default settings:

[image]

2. Then I added my ISO and changed the boot order:

[image]

But after starting the machine I get the following error:

```
FATAL: No bootable medium found! System halted.
```

---

**Update**:

I checked both the md5 and sha1 hashes, they were both ok.

This confirms the download size:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT2: You're trying to boot the language pack, not the installation medium.

EDIT1: just re-checking my microsoft secure download manager:[image: screenshot of download]

Might be a bit hard to read, but it says 3GB right there.

Comment: I checked it's md5 and sha1 checksum, both were ok.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue. When booted into the Virtual machine, I went to Devices>Optical Drives and noticed that my ISO was attached to Sata Port 2. I detatched the ISO from Sata Port 2 and then attached it to Sata Port 1. That fixed it!

[Image of Devices>OpticalDrives>Sata Port 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5aMUj.png)